# AutoHotKey simulate active window

Tags: window, autohotkey, minecraft

I want to make a script which is able to press W in an inactive Minecraft window. So I tried it with "ControlSend". As result I got this:

```
#NoEnv
SendMode Input
SetWorkingDir %A_ScriptDir%
#SingleInstance Force


F6::
ControlGet, MC, Selected
return

F7::
ControlSend, %MC%, {Esc Down}, Minecraft* 1.17.1 - Mehrspieler (Drittanbieter-Server) ; sry that the Window title is German
ControlSend, %MC%, {Esc Up}, Minecraft* 1.17.1 - Mehrspieler (Drittanbieter-Server)
ControlSend, %MC%, {w Down}, Minecraft* 1.17.1 - Mehrspieler (Drittanbieter-Server)
return

F8::
ControlSend, %MC%, {w Up}, Minecraft* 1.17.1 - Mehrspieler (Drittanbieter-Server)
return
```

With this script I can get the window (F6) if I activate it, start pressing W (F7) if Im outside of it and deactivate W (F8) if Im outside. The Problem is, when the Window is inactive Mincraftt goes in the escape screen. Is there a way to tell the Window that it should be active?
Thanks for Helping

Comment: I guess this really isn't a question for this place, but the answer is to hit `F3` + `P` to disable automatic pausing. [List of Minecraft hotkeys](https://minecraft.fandom.com/wiki/Controls).

Comment: @0x464e That's only for Java... bedrock doesn't appear to have a way to disable the menu from popping up when you tab away.